# Manipulating and saving multiple files

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, cut

I have ~2k files that I want to extract 12 of 26 columns and save the extracted information into a new file.  I have been doing this for individual files using

```
cat "oldfile.csv" | grep -v "=" | cut -f 1-4,9,14,15,19,21,22,24,26 > newfile.csv
```

There must be a way to do all files with one Unix series of commands.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 4):

The shell can do loops:

```
for i in *.csv; do 
    grep -v "=" "$i" | cut -f 1-4,9,14,15,19,21,22,24,26 > "new.$i"
done
```

Although, if you have embedded field separators in your fields, this will bomb. But not because of the loop.

Comment: `$i` needs quoting, or it will break on filenames containing characters in IFS.

Comment: Spot on. I stand corrected.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to provide particular files as argument to a script e.g. script named `process_csv.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
for arg; do
    grep -v "=" "${arg}" | cut -f 1-4,9,14,15,19,21,22,24,26 > "${arg}.new"
done
```

Now you can run this script as following,

`./process_csv.sh *.csv` OR

`./process_csv.sh first.csv fifth.csv seventh.csv` OR

`./process_csv.sh somefile1 somefile2`

Before somebody points it out, in the above script, if you do not want to preserve the arguments you can use `shift` in the script.